# Install colortheme in Vim

Tags: vim

I am a new user of Linux Ubuntu and I am trying to copy and paste a colortheme in Vim's folder color but it seems to be owned by root and I can't paste it in there. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

1. For system-wide availability of the color theme, use `sudo` to copy it there:

   ```
   sudo cp colortheme.vim /usr/share/vim/vim74/colors
   ```
2. If that isn't necessary, use your own `vim` configuration folder:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.vim/colors
   cp colortheme.vim ~/.vim/colors
   ```

Comment: It says cp: missing destination file operand after ‘clearance.vim/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors’

Comment: @Adam You forgot a space between the filenames.